# Stored procedure doesn't recognize table created

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-express

I am trying to email the results of a query to myself in the case that someone else is running a stored procedure and an error occurs. This script is part of a larger program that generates schema, tables, view, jobs dynamically.

I have configured SQL Server according to this [database mail article from SQL Shack](https://www.sqlshack.com/database-mail-configuration-in-sql-server-express-edition/).

Below is the stored procedure that causes the error:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE Ido.ConfirmDataTypesMapped
    @ido_and_propertyNames nvarchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @idoName nvarchar(100) = (SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING(@ido_and_propertyNames, 0, CHARINDEX(',', @ido_and_propertyNames))))
    
    -- if count > 0 then column requested has data type that is not mapped
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM Ido.TypeConversionMap map 
        RIGHT JOIN
            (SELECT DISTINCT DataType 
             FROM ido.IdoProperties 
             WHERE PropertyName IN (SELECT TRIM(value) 
                                    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ido_and_propertyNames, ',') 
                                    WHERE TRIM(value) <> @idoName 
                                      AND TRIM(Value) <> 'NULL')
               AND CollectionName = @idoName) idoDataTypes ON map.CsiDatatype = idoDataTypes.DataType
            where map.DbDataType is null
        ) > 0
        begin
    
            create table MissingDataTypes (DataTypes nvarchar(1000))
    
    -- inserts the missing data types onto a comma-separated single line
            insert into MissingDataTypes (DataTypes) values 
            
                (
                    (select string_agg(idoDataTypes.DataType, ', ') DataTypes from Ido.TypeConversionMap map 
                    right join (
                                    select distinct DataType from ido.IdoProperties where PropertyName in
                                    (
                                    select trim(value) from string_split(@ido_and_propertyNames, ',') where trim(value) <> @idoName and trim(Value) <> 'NULL'
                                    )
                                    and CollectionName = @idoName
                                ) idoDataTypes on map.CsiDatatype = idoDataTypes.DataType
                
                    where map.DbDataType is null)
                )
    
    -- email the missing data types
            exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
            @profile_name = '___',
            @recipients = '___',
            @body = '___',
            @subject = '___',
            @from_address = '___',
            @reply_to = '___',
            @query = 'select * from MissingDataTypes;'
    
            drop table MissingDataTypes
    
        end
    end
```

I get this error:

> Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 53
> Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.

Tracing the procedure reveals:

```
exec sp_executesql      N'INSERT sysmail_query_transfer(uid, text_data) VALUES((@P1),
(@P2))',N'@P1 nchar(72), @P2 ntext',   N'E840B6A4-132F-430F-B821-64961EF5744C  ',
N'Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server ___,   Line 1 Invalid object name  
''MissingDataTypes''.'
```

I am explicitly creating the table in the procedure.

Why is this not working? Thanks

Comment: You may need a GO after the create table statement so SQL will recognize it otherwise it is in one big transaction and it does not see the table created.

Comment: Or just create a temp table instead since you are creating and then dropping it.  It will recognize the creation of a temp table.  Then when the SP is done running it auto drops the temp table.

Comment: I *assume* you aren't creating these tables in the table `msdb`, so the table `MissingDataTypes` *won't* exist in that database. You need to tell `sys.sp_send_dbmail ` what database that table is in.

Comment: @ThomA beat me to it. Check out  execute_query_database parameter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#----execute_query_database or add it to the table name as three-part name

Comment: Also, `sp_send_dbmail` isn't supported on SQL Server Express. You need to be using Standard as a minimum. [Relevant Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2022?view=sql-server-ver16#additional-database-services).

Comment: Uhh, if you drop the table, it's gone, i'm not sure if db mail has access to it later because the data and email isn't generated right when you execute the call but rather through some service broker magic later

Comment: @ThomA was correct. I fully qualified both the creation of the table & the query against it. The code is now working :)

Comment: @ThomA to your other point, SQL Server Express indeed support sp_send_dbmail. Few days ago I placed it on a client's SQLExress instance and have received email notification since then. For SQLExpress, I did have to create a PowerShell script & Task but the sproc itself functions

Comment: @Brad I originally tried with a temp table but experienced the error. I simply used #MissingDataTypes, let me know if there's something I missed

Comment: It could be an issue with the Create table inside the if statement.  Use a temp table and create it BEFORE the if statement.  So the table wont always be there, but SQL may not see that.  If you go with permeant table and drop it you would have to put the DROP outside the If statement as well.

Comment: Have you tried testing it outside of an SP as well?  That would be easier/faster to test.  You wont have to create the SP/push updates then call the SP.  Do it inline while testing then once you have it working then convert to an SP.

Comment: Local temp tables, e.g.: `#MissingDataTypes`, are only visible to the current SPID. That is to say sp_send_dbmail is opening a new connection via the sqlcmd library to execute its query so will not see any local temp tables. It might work with global temp tables, e.g.: `##MissingDataTypes`, but you're likely to run into concurrency issues (only one can exist at a time, other connections may drop it) as well as locking issues (the sqlcmd connection might block due to transaction-level locks from the originating connection)... same as with the current `MissingDataTypes` solution you're using.